# C# Method has 1 parameter but is invoked with 2 arguments

Tags: c#, object, mvvm

I have tried searching for information without any luck.

I've got a couple of `Classes`, for example `CarManufacturerModel` & `CarModelModel`.

In `CarManufacturerModel` I create some car makes, "Audi, mercedes, bmw", and in `CarModelModel` I create the Manufacturer's different models.

I want to create an object(s) of `CarModelModel` in `CarManufacturerModel` so that I can add the following models of that manufacturer in the object declaration. One manufacturer can for example have multiple models, 1-series, 2-series, etc.

Here's CarModelModel

```
    public class CarModelModel
{
    //public string CarModel { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> CarModels { get; set; }

    public CarModelModel(/*string carModel*/ObservableCollection<string>carModels)
    {
        //CarModel = carModel;
        CarModels = carModels;
    }

    public static CarModelModel Create(/*string carModel*/ObservableCollection<string>carModels)
        => new CarModelModel(/*carModel*/carModels);

}
```

Here's CarManufacturerModel - notice some code is  *commented out*

```
 public class CarManufacturerModel
{
    public string CarManufacturer { get; set; }

    public CarModelModel CarModel { get; set; }

    //public ObservableCollection<CarModelModel> CarModels { get; set; }

    private CarManufacturerModel(string carManufacturer, /*ObservableCollection<CarModelModel>carModels*/CarModelModel carModel)
    {
        CarManufacturer = carManufacturer;
        //CarModels = carModels;
        CarModel = carModel;

    }

    public static CarManufacturerModel Create(string carManufacturer, /*ObservableCollection<CarModelModel>carModels*/CarModelModel carModel)
        => new CarManufacturerModel(carManufacturer, carModel);

}
```

Here's the class where i declare the objects, CarManufacturerViewModel

```
public class CarManufacturerViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICarManufacturerViewModel
{
    private string _carYear;

    //private CarModelModel _selectedCarModel;
    private CarManufacturerModel _carManufacturer;

    //private ObservableCollection<CarModelModel> _carModels;
    private ObservableCollection<CarManufacturerModel> _carManufacturers;

    [DesignOnly(true)]
    public CarManufacturerViewModel()
    {
        CarManufacturers = new ObservableCollection<CarManufacturerModel>
        {
            CarManufacturerModel.Create("Audi", CarModelModel.Create("1", "2")) <---------------------
        };
        //SelectedCarManufacturer = CarManufacturers.First();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CarManufacturerModel> CarManufacturers
    {
        get => _carManufacturers;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _carManufacturers, value);
        }
    }

    public CarManufacturerModel SelectedCarManufacturer
    {
        get => _carManufacturer;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _carManufacturer, value);
            //LoadSelectedCar();
        }
    }
```

I get the error message "Method 'create' has 1 parameter(s) but is invoked with 2 argument(s)..

What am I doing wrong that would allow me to add multiple models to 1 manufacturer in the same object declaration?

**Update**

```
public CarManufacturerViewModel()
    {
        CarManufacturers = new ObservableCollection<CarManufacturerModel>
        {
            CarManufacturerModel.Create("Audi", CarModelModel.Create(new string[]{"A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"})),
            CarManufacturerModel.Create("Mercedes", CarModelModel.Create(new string[]{"A-Class", "B-Class", "C-Class", "E-Class", "S-Class"})),
            CarManufacturerModel.Create("BMW", CarModelModel.Create(new string[]{"1-Serie", "2-Serie", "3-Serie", "4-Serie", "5-Serie"})),
            CarManufacturerModel.Create("Volkswagen", CarModelModel.Create(new string[]{ "Golf", "Passat", "Arteon", "T-Cross","Up!"})),
            CarManufacturerModel.Create("Volvo", CarModelModel.Create(new string[]{"V60","V70","XC60","XC90","S90"}))
        };
        //SelectedCarManufacturer = CarManufacturers.First();
    }
```

I try to use this in my ListView now but it only shows string[]array

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      Margin="0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CarManufacturers}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCarModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemBase}"
                           TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"></Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ComboBoxItemTextBlock}"
                                       Text="{Binding CarModel.CarModelList}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

CarModelModel looks like this now.

```
 public class CarModelModel
{

    public string[] CarModelList { get; set; }

    public CarModelModel(string[]carModelList)
    {
        CarModelList = carModelList;
    }

    public static CarModelModel Create(string[]carModelList)
        => new CarModelModel(carModelList);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `CarCarModel.Create` method:

```
public static CarModelModel Create(ObservableCollection<string> carModels)
```

takes an `ObservableCollection<string>` as its single parameter.

You're trying to call it like:

```
CarModelModel.Create("1", "2")
```

That is, you're trying to pass two `string` parameters. However, it takes an `ObservableCollection<string>`, so you need to pass it an `ObservableCollection<string>`:

```
CarModelModel.Create(new ObservableCollection<string>() { "1", "2" });
```

---

I would question whether you want to use an `ObservableCollection<string>` here at all: you normally only use those in a ViewModel, and only when you're binding them through to the UI, and you're going to be adding and removing elements (and what those additions and removals to be shown in some UI element).

If you use an array of strings here instead:

```
public static CarModelModel Create(string[] carModels)
```

then you can declare it as a [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) array:

```
public static CarModelModel Create(params string[] carModels)
```

This means that you can call it as:

```
CarModelModel.Create("1", "2");
```

and the compiler will turn this into a call to create a new array for you:

```
CarModelModel.Create(new string[] { "1", "2" });
```

---

Also, I don't think your `Create` methods add anything: just use a normal constructor.

Comment: This will be displayed in a ui when the program is running. This is why I originally had an ObservableCollection<string>. 

I display the manufacturer's in a WPF ComboBox, and after selecting one manufacturer a ListBox get's populated with the respective models.

Comment: Do you intend to add or remove manufacturers while the list is displayed on the UI? If not, you probably don't need an `ObservableCollection`

Comment: No I do not, and therefore I do not need an observableCollection, as I do not change/ edit the values, I understand your point.

Comment: @FilipF36 Is that a new question? If so, ask a new question.

Comment: Is it a new question? I considered it a follow up on my previous issue?
I am not sure if I can actually add those value's in the CarModelModel or CarManufacturerModel instead of putting them inside the ViewModel? Or is this the "right" way to do it..? I am trying to learn the Mvvm pattern

Comment: Posted a new question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60094903/display-stringarray-in-listview-for-respective-object  I will select your answer as the correct as soon as it's solved.